# Render Data From Form on Submission in React

Tags: forms, reactjs, react-native

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here- this should be really simple, but I can't find the info I'm looking for.

I have a form component and I'm trying to be able to render another component, which is passed props from the form ONLY upon submit. As of right now, the component re-renders on handleChange but does not wait for handleSubmit.

```
class UserInfo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
          <h4>{this.props.name}</h4>
        </div>
      )
    }
} 

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      this.state = {name: ''}

    this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit= this.handleSubmit.bind(this); 
    } 

  handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({ name: event.target.value })
    }   

   handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
        this.setState({ name: this.state.name})
        alert(this.state.name + ' was submitted');
    }

    renderUserInfo() {
        return <UserInfo name={this.state.name} />
         } 

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Username: 
            <input type="text" name={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
       {this.renderUserInfo()}
      </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Worth noting, this is a simplified version of my problem and I will need "UserInfo" component to be a container eventually, hence the reason for making it a smart component.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not wait for handleSubmit" ?

Comment: Sorry, should’ve phrased that better- I’m exhausted. Basically, I can get UserInfo rendering and updating on the handleChange function but I want to prevent it from rendering anything until handleSubmit, and when I call handleSubmit, props seem to get reset because I can get it to alert what was submitted but the rendering of UserInfo disappears.

Comment: The component will re-render as the state is getting changed. That is why the UserInfo is being rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're updating the `name` onChange, the react re-renders the entire component. You can use a `submitted` flag to check whether the info is submitted or not.

```
class SearchForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      this.state = {
       name: '',
       submitted: false }

    this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit= this.handleSubmit.bind(this); 
    } 

  handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({ name: event.target.value })
    }   

   handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
        this.setState({ submitted: true })
        alert(this.state.name + ' was submitted');
    }

    renderUserInfo() {
        return <UserInfo name={this.state.name} />
         } 

    render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Username: 
            <input type="text" name={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
       {this.state.submitted && this.renderUserInfo()}
      </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this and something similar last night. It prevents the text from being rendered on handleChange and receives the correct input upon submission but does not render anything on the screen.

Comment: This is spot on. Nice.